# How to Create Multiple Selection in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create like a simple form with multiple choice for my school project.
so how do I create a multiple form like this using django?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebsBW.png [1]

Comment: This is a really broad question to ask. The following link can help you get started. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Comment: I don't think this is a Django question. It more of an HTML CSS question. Are you for the from end of the backend?

Comment: the backend, i have no idea how to build the backend using django. been struggling for days how to send the request